# Sqlite3 database did not commit using php PDO

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I have used php PDO for sqlite3 database. This database access multiple application so I have applied WAL mode in sqlite3 database.

My problem is that I have one php file, it run infinite in backend for insert/update data in sqlite3. its works fine but sqlite3 create temp file for -WAL mode (databasename-wal). But -wal file size is increase constantly , How to commit the -WAL File data into main database file.

I have Tried below code for this issue, but it will not workin.

```
try {
            $dbhandle = new PDO("sqlite:".SQLITE_DB_PATH.DBNAME);
            return $dbhandle;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            /*echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;*/
        }

$dbhandle->beginTransaction();
$dbhandle->query($query);
$dbhandle->commit();
$dbhandle=null;
```

Answer (score 0):

To merge the WAL file into the main database file, run [PRAGMA wal_checkpoint](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_wal_checkpoint).

This [happens automatically](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_wal_autocheckpoint) when the WAL files reaches a size of 4 MB.

Comment: Thanks for reply I have already tried this and I have also change number of pages of check point.But my requirement is that I am not wait for reaches database size I want to commit when transaction is complete

Comment: The `-wal` file is not temporary. But if you don't want it, don't use WAL.

Comment: I know -wal file is not temporary but this file size is increased continuously instead of store data in main database after commit.My problem is that I have execute begin transaction and commit after each query then why-wal file size is increase ? why data did not store in main database ?

Comment: WAL is *designed* so that `COMMIT` appends changes to the WAL file instead of writing them to the main database file.